# How can a BizTalk error report not have an ErrorReport.FailureTime

Tags: error-handling, biztalk, biztalk-2010

How can a BizTalk error report not have an `ErrorReport.FailureTime` property value?

I've just got a batch of errors where the cause is the property `ErrorReport.FailureTime` has no value associated ...

But isn't this system generated are part of the error handling process?

And assuming that's correct, how can it not have a time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of nor have I encountered a situation where `ErrorReport.FailureTime` would be blank.

Yes, it is system generated, as are all `ErrorReport` Properties.